# Compilation of FFMPEG Decoder BY mooncatventures-group

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, static-libraries

I download FFMPEG Decoder from [here](https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/ffmpegDecoder) but i am unable to compile as i know nothing about static libraries (does it to be added in a project as static library or some static library to be added in this project). If static library to be added into this project how i can create a static library and link that to this project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add path of your static library in your xcode->build settings-> search path-> framework search path